# Prove that the midpoint of $XY = AB$

Tags: geometry

> Prove that given two point in the plane $A$ and $B$, the midpoint of $AB$ is the same as the midpoint of two points on $AB$, which are $X$ and $Y$ such that $AX = BY$.

I have a few ideas for how to prove this. It seems pretty intuitive at first that this must be true by drawing a few pictures, and I think an algebra proof will suffice for this one. However it might get a bit messy, so I was wondering what would be an efficient way to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It's important that $X$ and $Y$ lie on *segment* $\overline{AB}$, not necessarily $AB$.  Otherwise, this proof fails.

EDIT2: The user below me implicitly pointed out a fallacy in my original argument; it has been fixed.

But in any case, a short chain of reasoning is the following: let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$.  Assume WLOG that $AX<AM$; otherwise, we can simply swap $X$ and $Y$ to get an isomorphic proof.  But note that from $AX=BY$ we have $$AM-AX=BM-BY\implies MX=MY,$$ so $M$ is the midpoint of $XY$ as well.  $\blacksquare$

Comment: So if we wanted to prove the statement if $X$ and $Y$ are not on $\overline{AB}$ but rather line ${AB}$, would the proof be similar?

Comment: The proof would be false :P  (In particular, take, say, A, X, B, Y collinear in that order.)

Answer (score 0):

Let the midpoint be called M.

Case 1 A, X, and M are colinear.  Then AM = 1/2 AB = MB and AM = AX + XM.  Now YM = XM < AM = MB, so B, Y, and M. Are colinear and MB = YB + YM.  But AM = MB and XA = BY so YB + YM = AX + MX so YM = MX so M is the midpoint of XY.

Case 2 A, M, X are colinear.  Proof similar.